# How to select characters from a line number using cut command

Tags: bash, shell, unix, terminal

I am trying to see if there is a way to use the cut command but starting from a specifed line number.

For Example I cat the following file with the following command

```
cat -n client_custom.css
```

Then I got the following

```
  1 /* LEFT FRAME */
 2  /* Don't change this setting */
 3  /* Heading image setting */
 4  
 5  /* Use this line to repeat main_bg image */
 6  div#header{background:url(main_bg.jpg) 0 0 repeat-x;}
 7  /* Use this line if you have 1 big main_bg image and you don't want to repeat it 
 8  div#header{background:url(main_bg.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;}
 9  */
10  
11  div#header-left{ background:url(left_bg.png) center 0px  no-repeat; width:100%; } 
12
```

Lets say for example I would like to cut 2,6 on line number 11. Would guys know if there is a way of doing that?

Comment: what does that mean: "I would like to cut 2,6 on line number 11"? Show, don't tell

Answer (score 0):

IS it what you expect ?

```
$ grep '^11\b' file | cut -d ' ' -f2-6
```

Output:

```
 div#header-left{ background:url(left_bg.png) center 0px
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd look at sed

```
sed -n 11p
```

See it **[Live On IdeOne](http://ideone.com/lZYy02)**

This way you don't even need the line numbering (also `nl` is available for numbering lines)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That did the job. I am new to using unix.  I thought that sed was used for find and replace only... My question is what does the 'p' stand for in '11p' ?? Thanks!

Comment: My questions is why can't I use this using grep?

Comment: Basically, because grep is a different program. Of course you can use grep too (`grep '^11 '` for a start)

Comment: Just out of curiosity i tried using `cat -n client_custom.css | grep '^11'`  and it returned blank.....

Comment: This implies to me that your lines start with whitespace, in which case even more reason to use the proper tool :)